# Having a problem with a pivot table on Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a form with two pivot tables. One of them works just fine but I can't seem to be making the second one work despite them being quite similar. The one not working is for an image table called 'photos' and the form upload in called 'releases'. I called the pivot table 'photo_releases' with the 'photo_id' and a 'release_id' field.

[DB Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5pT4.jpg)

here is the release Modal

```
    class Release extends Model
    {
        public function photos()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Photo', 'photo_releases', 'release_id', 'photo_id');
        }
    }
```

and the photo modal

```
    class Photo extends Model
    {
        public function releases()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Release', 'photo_releases', 'photo_id', 'release_id');
        }
    }
```

and the ReleaseController

```
public function store(ReleasesCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $user = Auth::user();

        if ($file = $request->file('photo_01')) {
            $file_name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/", "", $file->getClientOriginalName());
            $name = time() . 'photo_01' . $file_name;
            $file->move('images', $name);
            $input['photo_01'] = $name;
            $photo = new Photo();
            $photo->url = $input['photo_01'];
            $photo->save();
        }

        $release = Release::create($request->except('release_id'));

        dd($request->except('release_id'), $request->get('photo_id', []), $request->get('artiste_id', []));
        $release->photos()->attach($request->get('photo_id', []));
        $release->artistes()->attach($request->get('artiste_id', []));

        return redirect('/admin06000/releases');
    }
```

There is two pivot tables being used in this function. the one using

"$release->artistes()->attach($request->get('artiste_id', []));"

is working correctly but the photos is not. The url is being logged in the correct DB and the image is uploading fine, but the pivot table is not being updated. If anyone could help it would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: I think I figured it out by doing this

$release->photos()->attach($photo->id);

If anyone can confirm it would be peachy.

Comment: By not working, could you explain more about what doesn't work? I want to help but so far I am not quite sure what is the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

try This if you need some select in relation ship change

```
 with('photos')
```

to

```
 with(['photos'=>function($query){$query->where(....)->get();}])...
```

````
 use Image;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
 ...
 public function store(ReleasesCreateRequest $request)
 {
             $input = $request->all();   
             $user = Auth::user();

             if ($file = $request->file('photo_01'))
             {
                 $image= Input::file('photo_01');
                 $name = time().'photo_01'.'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                 $path=public_path('/YourPath/'.$name);
                 Image::make($image->getRealPath())->save($path);


                 $photo = new Photo();
                 $photo->url = '/YourPath/'.$name;
                 $photo->save();
             }

             $release = Release::create
             ([
              'release_field'=>$amount,
              'release_field2'=>$amount2,
               ....
             ]); 

             $release->with('photos')->with(artistes)->get();



         }```
````